# Doctrine 2.0 ReflectionException when I try to do YAML Mapping

Tags: php, orm, doctrine, yaml, doctrine-orm

I have in my cli-config.php this code:

```
 $driverImpl = new \Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\YamlDriver(array(__DIR__.'/yaml'));
 $driverImpl->setFileExtension('.yml');
 $config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);
```

In ./yaml there are the yml files (Client.yml,Worker.yml,Company.yml)

When i run the file to generate in db the schema with this instruccion:

```
php doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
```

throws:

```
PHP Warning:  class_parents(): Class Client does not exist and could not be loaded in applicationPath\system\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222

Warning: class_parents(): Class Cliente does not exist and could not be loaded in applicationPath\\system\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222
PHP Warning:  array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in applicationPath\\system\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222

Warning: array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in applicationPath\\system\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in applicationPath\\system\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222

Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in applicationPath\\system\application\libraries\Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 222



  [ReflectionException]
  Class Client does not exist
```

It´s the same that Doctrine documentation http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/yaml-mapping.html

I don´t why it´s happening this, any idea? 
Thanks

Comment: I'm noticing that the first warning says "Class Client does not exist.." while the second one says "Class Cliente does not exist..". Are you sure there's no typo in your class names?

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, the SchemaTool will generate the SQL based on ClassMetadata instances, not directly from your YAML mappings. ClassMetadata instances require your actual entity classes as well

Make sure your command line tool has all your entity classes loaded/autoloaded.

Comment: Well, I don´t know how i have to do it. Could you show me an example?

Comment: can you please describe further what you mean "make sure you command line tool has all your entity classes loaded?

Answer (score -1):

I faced the same trouble. The trick is to generate entities from the yaml files with the --generate-annotations options set to 1. I've copied the command I used below :

```
$ doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=1 Entities/
```

What this does is that it generates the entities along with all mapping information. Now if you change the Metadata driver config in your bootstrap to use the Entities instead of the yaml files the schema creation should work.

EDIT 2017-05-31
Revisiting this after a while. This looks like a case of Doctrine not being able to locate your "Class Client" due to autoloading issues. You could fix this by including the path to your bootstrap file / autoloader script in your cli-config.php .