# Doctrine 2 configuration problem, can't seem to find entities

Tags: doctrine-orm

As a Doctrine 2.1 newbie I am trying to get started using Doctrine 2 but am stuck at what seems something basic. But still I can't wrap my head around it:

Running

```
$ doctrine orm:generate-entities Entities

Processing entity "MyUser"

Entity classes generated to "/home/lucvh/NetBeansProjects/doctrinetest/Entities"
```

Generates what the MyUser.php file I would expect (see below)

I then proceed to generating the schema which fails apparently because the classloader is not working as it doesn't seem to find the MyUser class which is located beneath the Entities dir. What am I missing.....

```
$ doctrine orm:schema-tool:create
PHP Warning:  class_parents(): Class MyUser does not exist and could not be loaded in /usr/share/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 223
PHP Warning:  array_reverse() expects parameter 1 to be array, boolean given in /usr/share/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 223
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /usr/share/php/Doctrine/ORM/Mapping/ClassMetadataFactory.php on line 223



  [ReflectionException]        
  Class MyUser does not exist  



orm:schema-tool:create [--dump-sql]
```

MyUser.php:

```
<?php



use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;

/**
 * MyUser
 */
class MyUser
{
    /**
     * @var string $Firstname
     */
    private $Firstname;

    /**
     * @var string $Lastname
     */
    private $Lastname;

    /**
     * @var string $Email
     */
    private $Email;

    /**
     * @var boolean $Enabled
     */
    private $Enabled;

    /**
     * @var integer $Id
     */
    private $Id;


    /**
     * Set Firstname
     *
     * @param string $firstname
     */
    public function setFirstname($firstname)
    {
        $this->Firstname = $firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Get Firstname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getFirstname()
    {
        return $this->Firstname;
    }

    /**
     * Set Lastname
     *
     * @param string $lastname
     */
    public function setLastname($lastname)
    {
        $this->Lastname = $lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Get Lastname
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getLastname()
    {
        return $this->Lastname;
    }

    /**
     * Set Email
     *
     * @param string $email
     */
    public function setEmail($email)
    {
        $this->Email = $email;
    }

    /**
     * Get Email
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getEmail()
    {
        return $this->Email;
    }

    /**
     * Set Enabled
     *
     * @param boolean $enabled
     */
    public function setEnabled($enabled)
    {
        $this->Enabled = $enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Get Enabled
     *
     * @return boolean 
     */
    public function getEnabled()
    {
        return $this->Enabled;
    }

    /**
     * Get Id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->Id;
    }
}
```

contents of config/mappings/xml/MyUser.dcm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<doctrine-mapping xmlns="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping" xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" schemaLocation="http://doctrine-project.org/schemas/orm/doctrine-mapping.xsd">
  <entity name="MyUser">
    <id name="Id" type="integer">
      <generator strategy="AUTO"/>
    </id>
    <field name="Firstname" type="string" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="Lastname" type="string" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="Email" type="string" nullable="true"/>
    <field name="Enabled" type="boolean" nullable="true"/>
  </entity>
</doctrine-mapping>
```

contents of cli-config.php

```
<?php
require_once '/usr/share/php/Doctrine/Common/ClassLoader.php';


$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Entities', __DIR__);
$classLoader->register();

$classLoader = new \Doctrine\Common\ClassLoader('Proxies', __DIR__);
$classLoader->register();

$config = new \Doctrine\ORM\Configuration();
$config->setMetadataCacheImpl(new \Doctrine\Common\Cache\ArrayCache);
$config->setProxyDir(__DIR__ . '/Proxies');
$config->setProxyNamespace('Proxies');


$driverImpl = new Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\Driver\XmlDriver(__DIR__."/config/mappings/xml");
$config->setMetadataDriverImpl($driverImpl);


$connectionOptions = array(
    'driver' => 'pdo_pgsql',
    'host' => 'localhost',
    'user' => 'xxx',
    'password' => 'xxx',
    'dbname' => 'xx'
);

$em = \Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager::create($connectionOptions, $config);

$helperSet = new \Symfony\Component\Console\Helper\HelperSet(array(
    'db' => new \Doctrine\DBAL\Tools\Console\Helper\ConnectionHelper($em->getConnection()),
    'em' => new \Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Helper\EntityManagerHelper($em)
));

?>
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem could be caused because you are not loading your module.

In case you use ZF2 make sure you add the module in application.config.php.
In case you use ZF3 you should include it in modules.config.php

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

If someone else has got the same problem, the following post from the linked thread might help:

[Doctrine 2.0 ReflectionException when I try to do YAML Mapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4860856/doctrine-2-0-reflectionexception-when-i-try-to-do-yaml-mapping)

> I faced the same trouble. The trick is to generate entities from the
>   yaml files with the --generate-annotations options set to 1. I've
>   copied the command I used below :
>
> $ doctrine orm:generate-entities --generate-annotations=1 Entities/
>
> What this does is that it generates the entities along with all
>   mapping information. Now if you change the Metadata driver config in
>   your bootstrap to use the Entities instead of the yaml files the
>   schema creation should work.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, when I've got the same troubles, the reason was that there was no namespace.
As you can see in your generated Entity there is no namespace, so Doctrine couldn't find it.

Comment: Where should this namespace be added / What is the missing namespace?